# Wiremock Doesn't Mock the Webclient Request

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, junit5, wiremock

I am using spring boot 2.5.7, java 8 and junit 5.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.7</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My integration test class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyTestApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)
@DirtiesContext
public class MyTestControllerTest {

  @LocalServerPort
  private int port;

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

  @BeforeEach
  void init() {
    stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("http://localhost:8443/my-third-party-endpoint"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
            .withStatus(200)
            .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
            .withHeader("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
            .withBody("{}")));
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddEmployee() {
    PartInspectionImageModel partInspectionImageModel = new PartInspectionImageModelProvider().createPartInspectionImageModel();

    ResponseEntity<PartInspectionImageModel> responseEntity = this.restTemplate
        .postForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/rest/my-test-endpoint", partInspectionImageModel, PartInspectionImageModel.class);

    assertEquals(200, responseEntity.getStatusCodeValue());
  }
}
```

Code piece to be mocked by wiremock inside my implementation class:

```
 WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8443");

  Mono<String> postPartInspectionImageModelToML = webClient.post()
      .uri("/my-third-party-endpoint")
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .body(Mono.just(completeMlProcessingModel), CompleteMlProcessingModel.class)
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(String.class);

  String response = postPartInspectionImageModelToML.block();
```

Due to it can't be mocked, test failing at postPartInspectionImageModelToML.block() phase.

Error is only:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further
> information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you're running WireMock on port 8443 if you hardcode `http://localhost:8443` as the base URL for your `WebClient`.

As of now, you start WireMock on a random port `@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 0)`. That's also possible if you dynamically override the base URL for your WebClient by e.g. outsourcing it to a configuration value.

Otherwise, try to change it to `@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8443)`.